# Is it possible to define a class in a method?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

Is it possible to define a class in a method?

```
private function someMethod():void {

            class lol{

            }

        }
```

Comment: Why do you need this? I'm pretty sure you can achieve the result another way. Why don't you use private class outside a method?

Comment: The answer is obvious, no.

Answer (score 0):

it's possible with the as3-commons emit api: http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-bytecode/emit.html

Answer (score 0):

Actionscript 3.0 doesn't support nested classes, you can see the documentation about the topic here [Packages and namespaces](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9e.html) , you can make local or nested classes in java.